# Looking for AWS CLI equivalent for s3cmd --delete-removed

Tags: aws-cli, s3cmd

I'm moving from `s3cmd` tool to the official `aws` CLI tool distributed by Amazon, and as I'm converting old scripts, I'm curious about how to construct this equivalent command:

`s3cmd --delete-removed sync s3://$BUCKET $LOCAL_DIR/`

From the `s3cmd` documentation, I see that `--delete-removed` is defined as: `Delete remote objects with no corresponding local file`.

However, which is considered the remote and which is considered the local here? I am worried that the `aws s3 sync` command with the `--delete` flag will not be render the same results.

Are

`s3cmd --delete-removed sync s3://$BUCKET $LOCAL_DIR/`

and

`aws s3 sync s3://$BUCKET $LOCAL_DIR/ --delete`

the same commands?

Thank you for your help in untangling my confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that they are the same.

Based on the aws cli  [s3 sync documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html#options),

> --delete (boolean) Files that exist in the destination but not in the source are deleted during sync

So in your case,

```
aws s3 sync s3://$BUCKET $LOCAL_DIR/ --delete
```

will copy all files in `s3://$BUCKET` to `$LOCAL_DIR/`, but delete files in `$LOCAL_DIR/` if they don't exist in `s3://$BUCKET`

Check under the [example section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html#examples) for an example of this